# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript

I have the following code

```
  dispatchEvent(name: TableEventName, params: any): any {
    const event =
      typeof this.options?.event?.[name] === 'function' ? this.options.event[name] : () => {}
    return event(params)
  }
```

which at compilation return

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'. return event(params)

I am doing the correct checking tho, why so ?

full code :

```
type TableEventName = 'onStateChange' | 'onSort' | 'onPageChange' | 'onSelection'

interface TableOptions {
  event?: {
    onStateChange?: (event: any) => void
    onSort?: (event: any) => void
    onPageChange?: (event: any) => void
    onSelection?: (event: any) => void
  }
}

let options: TableOptions = {
    event: {
        onSort: () => { } 
    }
}

let dispatcher = function (name: TableEventName, params: any): any {
    const event =
      typeof options?.event?.[name] === 'function' ? options.event[name] : () => {}
    return event(params)
}
```

[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=2#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgQwEYBsoFEBuUB2IByCAtrALwwDkA9jgMogIhQDCAFgjgOZQUwA%20lGrSoAnELwHUcABQTc2HbhMF0oaAMYgAljQrBgWvFBEAzBOtiJUUAPIRtNAM4wA3sBgwo2PAH4AXK7uHir0jCzsXDz%20MAAUXrggARxgAJQwpAB8MJhUWgAmQR5SwmIU0XHeiTDJaZnZuQXBMDSy8hHc5fF4STip6Vk5%20YXNqhoOOJ2VPX11g40wAL7AS8BoIM32OjiOAVZoduPO5G5NXVUnTcFColUxtVkuizDDSytrMHlajhCM6qzG6RgJgArjhNFtYjhiFBdsg0FgEoQSAAaGA-ETEHbVXopaaBJrqJzrM7pYYecDQKgmDaHHwAOjO9IA2lCSABddKkcgUEFg8a8Hw0raOBmVFnQjkBO79VxLJoiKAgYEiHCeSoxdGYlLLIA)

Comment: Could you include all the code required to reproduce it? Preferably a TypeScript Playground.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVsgbwFgAoZc5AewAcxhKQBnAfgC5DkIA3CcNjgNoBrCOnaMwUUAHMAuuzgh0yAL6rSK0mHTUUAFTjYANhACiPcADk4AWxQBeZBKkhpAblKkYAVxAI6DMgAJsCM1HBgCAAW5rxgABRgUaHsGDi4ADTIILYQ7AbGZhZg1nZZ4VC2jApKAJQ1ysRkFAgMEpzFyPakFL3I2rqUMP3JjAB0NAFMzGPccTMCOXayXfaOAOQ+flPryMwjoRO09EyzxYu5K+zxtV0AfByazeRQEGDeUCAdcfEVVbUaIA). Can you supply a [mcve]?

Comment: @VLAZ I added full code, typescript 3.8.3

Comment: @KarolMajewski also notify you.

Comment: OK, I see the problem, then. `options?.event?.[name] === 'function'` is used once but TS doesn't know that `options.event[name]` will fetch the same element.

Comment: so this would be typescript problem ?

Comment: I will fix it with a tampon variable then thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage optional chaining:

```
let dispatcher = function (name: TableEventName, params: any): any {
  const handler = options.event?.[name];

  return handler?.(params);
}
```